Why are maximum age restrictions so rare?
As per Are there countries with upper age limits for voters or candidates? only Uganda has age restrictions for Presidential candidates. The Netherlands have a limit for mayors and some US states have a limit for judges.
But why are these restrictions so rare? Surely younger politicians would push for a limit to increase their chance of obtaining power before they are senile? And likewise (as evidenced by both Trump and Biden recently) voters don't want to see 80+ year olds running their country. Have there been any studies on this subject in political science?

It is worth noting that the same answer indicates that Uganda removed those restrictions. The current president-for-life has been in office for nearly 40 years and is 80 years old.

some  background reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_retirement

Perhaps most of the people in a position to impose such restrictions are the very people to whom those restrictions would apply. They'd effectively be legislating themselves out of a job.

Because the people who make the rules generally are not in their 20s anymore?

@Tom if you're in your 50s you still want the 70 year olds to retire so that you get a chance to rule before you're senile yourself.

Why should the absolute age matter, as opposed to, say, competency? Life expectancy keeps increasing, are you going to amend the constitution (or equivalent) every few years to reflect that?

@JonathanReez only if you're already near the top. If you are still working your way up, you want that extra time to get to the top.

Here is your problem:

Surely younger politicians would push for a limit to increase their chance of obtaining power

The people who would benefit from this aren't in office. The people that this would negatively impact are in office. What do you think they would vote for? The people in office would make government positions "for life, and maybe a little bit longer" if they thought that they could. That is the nature of politics.
Its kinda like expecting politicians to vote for a pay cut. While it has occasionally happened, it doesn't happen very often, and it's usually quietly removed soon after.
Or how CEOs layoff people instead of doing a C-Staff paycut. Generally speaking, people behave selfishly.

Or how CEOs layoff people instead of doing a C-Staff paycut => C-suite pay is usually <5% of total salary costs, so even if you fire them all you won't save all that much. It's a common fallacy and IMO your answer would be better off without it.

@JonathanReez, the point made is that people act selfishly, not that cutting C-staff pay saves more money than laying off hourly workers.

@MichaelHall the post says how CEOs layoff people instead of doing a C-Staff paycut, implying that layoffs can be avoided if you just cut C-suite pay. But reality is that no, it cannot be. It's a common fallacy and the post would be better off without it. Also see this wiki article.

@JonathanReez, I don't disagree that it implies what you are saying, only that it supports the point that was actually being made regarding acting in one's best self interest.  As far as the fallacy goes, it's a staffing math problem that doesn't have a single answer, because it's very easy to present a scenario where cutting C-staff pay is the best answer.

@MichaelHall if Questor said "like how CEOs cut C-suite pay instead of firing workers" (which did happen before in various companies) would you still agree its a relevant comment? After all, the inverse scenario can also be constructed. The CEO does benefit from not cutting workers in some scenarios - i.e. they get to claim a larger number of people managed on their resume for future jobs.

@JonathanReez, No, it would not be relevant because that would be an example of the opposite of selfish behavior.

It's not a fallacy. It may not have universal applicability, but there are clearly at least some high-profile cases where it is true. For instance, spread Elon Musk's 10-year pay package value out, and you see that it is worth USD 4 billion per year—equivalent to the salaries of about 40,000 of the more highly paid Tesla employees (not the stock clerks and whatnot). And that is just one person, not the whole set of top executives.

Hey, for that matter, the CEO at my (small, failing!) company has a yearly compensation of over USD 1.5 million, maybe equivalent to about 18 of the better-paid employees. Not much compared to good old overcompensated Elon? Maybe, but at a company with only about 300 employees, that is a fair bit. And at the same time they bring in this CEO, they fire one of the longest-tenured and highest-performing scientists (still making rather less than 1.5 million) to "save money," never mind that no one else really knows how to do some of what she was doing.

@JonathanReez I know businesses where the CEO's/C level staff have taken paycuts to avoid firing people. In this instance by doing C-staff led pay cuts that trickled down until they had enough savings to avoid layoffs. Side note this allowed said company to massively outperform all of its competitors the next year, because they hadn't cut staff. I also know that for a lot of companies it wouldn't do anything for, but When you see a company doing massive layoffs because they are struggling financially, and the CEO gets a huge performance bonus? Not a good look

@Questor what was the ratio of C-suite salaries (in cash, not options with a long vesting period) to everyone else's salaries in said company? It doesn't seem realistic that C-suite cuts actually helped much, other than the morale aspect.

@Obie2.0 Elon was only paid that much because he 10x'd the stock value over 5 years, which is an insane feat and delivered huge pay increases to thousands of employees as well. If stock price stayed ~same, he would've been paid much less. So not a valid example.

@Obie2.0 as for your small, failing company: was the CEO paid that much in cash? If yes, then sure, its a valid example. But usually C-suite pay is structured in a way where they'll earn much, much less if the company ends up going under or if they get fired quickly.

@JonathanReez - The stock price increased. Whether he increased it, and to what extent, is very much a different question. Many CEOs are very good at persuading people when the company does well, it is because of them, never mind "market forces," and when it does poorly, it must be someone else's fault.

@Obie2.0 it doesn't matter whether he was personally responsible, the point is that his compensation package was conditional on the stock going up. So in a situation where layoffs are necessary (which would be pretty bad for stock prices) his compensation would be automatically cut down. Same applies to most C-suite employees, although cases of poor board decision making or outright fraud are not unheard of.

@Obie2.0 example from a small company I've worked for: new CEO got hired with ~10x my salary of which 2x was unconditional and 8x was conditional on tenure and performance. He got fired after 6 months so ended up getting just 2x my own pay.

@JonathanReez C-Suite cuts? no, But C-Suite Cuts + Management Cuts + Senior Engineering Cuts? Yes... Can't ask people to take a pay cut if you don't do it first

I guess it's a combination of the following:

Where would you reasonably draw that line?
While not causally related age correlates with experience
If they are young and successful they stick until they are old...
Old people know the game and have the networks. Know the powerful people, as the people older then them dropped out, while their generational peers are the one in power and they know them better either personally or what events shaped them...
... Which can be used actively (by themselves) and passively ("Hey could YOU talk to them about this proposal"), but either way makes them stay.
As politicians they are able to make the rules, so given they are old why would they restrict themselves
Old people have build a reputation for themselves, which might exceed themselves. So they might remain as figureheads and straw man for other individuals, groups and movements.
The thing is the image of what a person is like doesn't update if you don't see them regularly or only see them in staged events, so they can maintain an image for much longer than they would reasonably be able to do in real life and some people might depend on that and facilitate it because of that.
That's really not a novel thing, "senate" is literally derived from "council of old people".
The thing is statistical arguments about the development of people are not perfect, but when it comes to the human development the stages into adulthood are usually a lot more similar than the paths of life you take afterwards and in consequences the paths in which you decay. There are people who decay early, while others stay fit for a long time, in some cases the body takes a toll but the mind is still sharp, while in other cases the body might stay healthy but the mind is slowly fading. And that can be a slower or faster process and is subject to individual parameters. So one line to catch them all is difficult.

Also if you were to set one down, you'd need to adjust that with life expectancy and advances in medicine and in general unless they are so mentally unfit that they need a legal and medical guidance, removing their active and passive voting right IS A HUGE VIOLATION OF THEIR HUMAN RIGHT AND CITIZEN RIGHTS. Seriously don't take that lightly with an ever increasing population you would essentially form a growing group of second class citizens. That also applies to young people but usually the voting right is granted around the age where they'd realize they're getting screwed out of it.

Also, you bring up that senate means "council of old people", but when that term was coined, people lived much shorter than now. 45-50 was the life expectancy (after age 10) vs 80+ now, and indeed many politicians in current day are way older than 50.

@ave Sure but 50 back than also likely meant end of life health problems, while those might nowadays come later statistically

As another example, the Kingdom of Denmark (Europe) has a maximum age for judges and shorter validity of drivers licenses above about 70 years old.  For driver licenses, old drivers just need to get regularly updated signatures from a doctor that they are still physically and mentally fit to drive (not blind or senile), doctors are supposed to examine the driver before signing that.  For judges, the constitution specifies "A judge who has completed his 65. year may, however, be retired, but without loss of income up to the time when he is due for retirement on account of age" (that ordinary retirement age for judges is about 70).  There is (for the reasons discussed in other answers) no maximum age for other high offices, nor for the ability to vote or stand in elections, in fact the election law has special provisions to facilitate voting by people who are blind or confined to an institution, unless under a conservatorship .

Simply because the life expectancy has increased a lot since various constitutions originally written and the issue of age and people in the 80+ age bracket holding office wasn't an issue.
Even if you only go back to 1860 the life expectancy has almost doubled from almost 40 to almost 80
Life expectancy (from birth) in the United States, from 1860 to 2020*
In the case of Uganda it was written in 1995 which means that modern life expectancy was likely taken into account.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I was looking at the citation you provided and was trying to figure out if there was a way to eliminate childhood deaths from the calculation (I couldn't figure out a way to). I think if you could incorporate that kind of result, you'd have a strong answer.

This citation might make the point against you as it suggests an average lifespan once a child reaches 5 years old to be about 75 (for men) in the Victorian era. Curiously, women's average age is 73 for that time frame, however, dying in childbirth is a common cause of death in that era so maybe that pulls the number down.

As one data point, the average age of death of 15/16 of the US founding fathers (excepting Alexander Hamilton, for obvious reasons) was 73.

While I somewhat agree with the premise (+1), I am fairly certain that the typical reported hundreds of years ago (but not all that long ago) life expectancy of 40 or 50 or similar includes both a huge amount of child mortality (much of that being for diseases that we have vaccinated away), wars (affecting typically late teens through 20s - and still a problem in some places but overall much less than it used to be) where pre-antibiotic and pre-modern surgery fatalities were extremely common for injuries that in the 20th century would have sent the soldiers home to recover.

And also a lot of deaths of women in childbirth. People who made it past those stages had a decent chance of living to 60 or 70 or more.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact is correct. We get constantly mislead by reported averages. Even in the dark ages, if you made it into adulthood (which only half of children did) and avoided dying in war or plague, you would likely reach retirement age. The maximum age of people not dying from violence or disease has increased, but not by all that much.
